# ApplicationServices Framework not found error in ios

Tags: iphone

I am trying to reuse one code in ios application . That code has several frameworks for mac and ios both . I don't know which file is for mac os and which one is for ios , so I included all in new project ,Included frameworks also , But I am receiving error for Application services framework . I know Application Services framework is only available for MAC Os not for ios . But If I delete ApplicationServices framework from my project then it will give more errors , since it is being used in some class. Here is my error log

```
ld /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FlacPlayerUniversal-bupfypehvcjbrofyhhjbqudwhdre/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FlacPlayerUniversal.app/FlacPlayerUniversal normal i386
    cd "/Users/Documents/ios5 Examples/FlacPlayerUniversal"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FlacPlayerUniversal-bupfypehvcjbrofyhhjbqudwhdre/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator "-L/Users/Documents/ios5 Examples/FlacPlayerUniversal/opt/iphone-4.3/lib" "-L/Users/Documents/ios5 Examples/FlacPlayerUniversal/opt/iphone-simulator-4.3/lib" -F/Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FlacPlayerUniversal-bupfypehvcjbrofyhhjbqudwhdre/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator "-F/Users/Documents/ios5 Examples/FlacPlayerUniversal" -F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FlacPlayerUniversal-bupfypehvcjbrofyhhjbqudwhdre/Build/Intermediates/FlacPlayerUniversal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FlacPlayerUniversal.build/Objects-normal/i386/FlacPlayerUniversal.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50000 -framework CoreGraphics -framework ApplicationServices -framework Accelerate -framework CoreFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreAudio -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -lFLAC++ -lFLAC -lmpg123 -logg -lsndfile -lspeex -lspeexdsp -lvorbis -lvorbisenc -lvorbisfile -lwavpack -lFLAC++ -lFLAC -lmpg123 -logg -lsndfile -lspeex -lspeexdsp -lvorbis -lvorbisenc -lvorbisfile -lwavpack -o /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FlacPlayerUniversal-bupfypehvcjbrofyhhjbqudwhdre/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FlacPlayerUniversal.app/FlacPlayerUniversal

ld: framework not found ApplicationServices
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang++ failed with exit code 1
```

Please help to solve this error .

Comment: Well you can't fix this the way you want. You just can't use frameworks that are not available on iOS. Os you will need to remove the code that use the OSX frameworks. There is no magical setting here that will help you fix it, especial since you don't tell use which framework you are talking about.

Comment: @rckoenes I have specified ApplicationServices framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OS X and iOS have similar but not the same frameworks. You should remove anything which depends on OS X frameworks not available for iOS.

Answer (score 2):

The ApplicationServices framework is not available on iOS. So you need to modify your framework so that it doesn't attempt to link to the ApplicationServices framework for its iOS variant. It thus also may not try to call any Mac OS X specific functions or reference any Mac OS X specific symbols when you compile for iOS. There is no way to make it work otherwise.